# Messages auto forwarding in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible in ActiveMQ to auto forward a message from one topic to another after a specific time of interval.

Comment: Can you add more details? Do you have already tried some code?

Comment: Hi Piero, thanks for replying. I have a simple producer and a consumer consuming from topic 'sample', messages are getting consumed fine. During processing if any exception occurred the message is auto send to a another topic 'sampleErrorTopic'. I want to have a mechanism that will auto forward these messages (from topic 'sampleErrorTopic') to a third topic 'sampleReplay' after 10 minutes.  Hope this will clear you the usecase.

Comment: Set a TTL of 10 minutes for the messages you send to `sampleErrorTopic`. Then configure `sampleReplay` as the dead letter queue. See [DLQ](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) documentation for AMQ.

Comment: @Ralf great reply. Can you make that an answer? I think it answers the question.

Comment: @PetterNordlander, yes it will be very helpful.